# Closed form for a binomial identity

Tags: binomial-coefficients

$\textrm {How do I find a closed form for } \sum_{j=0}^n{} j\displaystyle\binom{j}{r} = ?$

Is this some kind of upper index summation?

Any previous papers?

Thank you

Comment: What is $r$? Is it a parameter?

Comment: [see here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bj*Binomial%5Bj%2Cr%5D%2C%7Bj%2C1%2Cn%7D%5D)

Comment: Nice, but is this equivalent to the result of Mr. Andrews??   See below

Comment: Sorry, what does on hold mean??, One member understood and solved the problem! Does it mean that the question is not active anymore??

Comment: r is any natural number, Stella

Comment: No need to reopen, the OP has asked this question already [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632261/closed-form-for-a-binomial-identity-another-solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n}{r}x^n = \frac{x^r}{(1-x)^{r+1}}$$

Taking the derivative and multiplying by $x$ gives us:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\binom{n}{r} x^{n} = \frac{x^{r+1}+ rx^{r}}{(1-x)^{r+2}}$$

Multiplying by $\frac{1}{1-x}$, we get:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}j\binom{j}{r}\right)=\frac{x^{r+1}+rx^r}{(1-x)^{r+3}}$$

Now, $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{r+3}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{r+k+2}{r+2}x^k$$

So $$\sum_{j=1}^{n}j\binom{j}{r} = \binom{n+1}{r+2} + r\binom{n+2}{r+2}$$

You can, perhaps, prove this directly by induction.

Another more direct approach would use:

$$(j+1)\binom{j}{r}= \frac{(j+1)!}{r!(r-j)!} = (r+1)\binom{j+1}{r+1}$$

Using this and some known formulas, we get that your sum is:

$$(r+1)\binom{n+2}{r+2}-\binom{n+1}{r+2}$$

This is, in fact, equal to my previous expression.

**Counting proof**

The left side $\sum_{j=1}^{n}j\binom{j}{r}$, counts the number of ways of picking $r+1$ elements of $\{1,2,3,\dots,n+1\}$, and then picking a free number less than the maximum in that set (the free number can be in the $r+1$-subset our not.) $j\binom{j}{r}$ counts the number of such selection where the set's maximum is $j+1$.

Now $(r+1)\binom{n+1}{r+2}$ counts the cases where the free number is chosen outside $r+1$-set - you pick $r+2$ numbers, then pick one of the non-maximum values as the free selection. Also, $r\binom{n+1}{r+1}$ counts the number of ways of picking the $r+1$ elements and then picking the free number as one of the $r$(non-maximal) elements of that set.

So: $$\sum_{j=1}^{n}j\binom{j}{r} = (r+1)\binom{n+1}{r+2}+r\binom{n+1}{r+1}$$

Again, using simple manipulation, you can see this is the same.

Comment: Nice, but where did you get the first expression??  Thank you!

Comment: The value $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{r+1}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k+r}{r}x^k$$ can be proved in a couple of ways. One way is to use induction on $r$ - with $r=0$, you get a standard series. For $r\to r+1$, you differentiate that case for $r$ and divide both sides by $r+1$ and show the right side is what you want.

Comment: The very first Sum, before taking derivative

Comment: Thank you! Your result is stil valid if j goes from 0 to n??

Comment: When $j=0$, $j\binom{j}{r}=0$, so adding $j=0$ does nothing to change the result. @frank

Comment: http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/34-3/jones.pdf      This identity is called "The extended hockey stick identity"